# Running a python timer after a other method has been called

Tags: python, kivy

Hello im doing a project for school right now and im working with the framework Kivy. It is based on python coding and im searching for a answer to my question.

```
t = 5

def countdown(t):
    
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
      
    print('Fire in the hole!!')

class ResetPopup(Popup):
    pass

class Widgets(Widget):
    def btn(self):
        popup = ResetPopup()
        popup.open()
        countdown(int(t))

class MyApp(App)
    def build(self):
        return Widgets()
```

Now when i open the popup with the button the timer starts to run first then then the popup wil open. Im searching a way to first open the popup and then start the timer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you just want the popup to *open* first, or do you want to wait to start the timer until someone actually pushes a button / closes the popup again?

Comment: So when the button is pressed i want the popup first to open and then the countdown timer. Now the countdown timer first triggers when the button is clicked and then the countdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `on_open` method. This method is fired when the popup is opened.You just have to add the method to your class definition :

```
class ResetPopup(Popup):
    def on_open(self):
        countdown(int(t)) #This fires your function when popup is opened
```

For more info:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html